# CSS hierarchy - div within div

Tags: css

I have some CSS that I've pieced together from a few sources, but my question is quite basic.

In this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ekbsb/1/  why does the outer div's UL CSS take precedence over the "downstream" div's UL rules?

To be specific:

```
#bodytopPan ul{margin:0px 0px 0px 25px; padding:0px;}
```

is overwriting this code:

```
.ILdropdown  ul{
    left: 0;
    margin: 5px 0;
}
```

Even though `.ILdropdown  ul` is placed "lower" in the HTML.  Isn't this the opposite of how it should be working??

My goal is to replace the `body ul` code with something for this specific instance.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSS ids (#) take precedence over classes (.)

Re-write it as follows:

```
#bodytopPan ul{margin:0px 0px 0px 25px; padding:0px;}

#bodytopPan .ILdropdown  ul{
    left: 0;
    margin: 5px 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## bodytopPan is an id, which is more specific than .ILdropdown, which is a class. the higher the specificity, the more emphasis placed on the declaration.

Answer (score 0):

It's not about the order in the HTML, its about the order in the CSS.

Edit: If you want to be specific (i.e only affect the main, first ul in "body" and no others, you can do `body > ul` which will only target unordered lists of which are direct children of the body. Obviously you probably won't have this case, more like `body > div > div > ul` but it lets you be more specific which UL you want to target (if it has no class)